# codeigniter session not set first time

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a problem. I am setting session on a login page. But when the page redirects where session does not initiate on the first attempt. When I login second time then session has set.

I am stuck what is the problem.

Here is my code

```
$data = $this->input->post();
    //$data['password'] = $this->encrypt->encode($data['password']);
    $result = $this->Login_m->get_userdata($data['username']);
    $result['password'] = $this->encrypt->decode($result['password']);
    //print_r($result);

    if (strtolower($data['username']) === strtolower($result['username']) and $data['password'] === $result['password'] ) {

        unset($result['password']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $result);
        redirect("dashboard");
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Given Username or Password is not correct");
        redirect("login");
        die();
    }
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do a `var_dump($this->session->userdata('user');` just before the `redirect` and see if the session is being set properly

Comment: Try redirect('dashboard', 'refresh'); Also, I now always access the session variable directly $_SESSION['some_name']. Just as an aside, encrypt encode and decode should NOT be used for passwords. You should use one way hashing only. It is well described in php.net here http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Thank you soo much for your information. #PaulD. I will follow this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of browser cache. Try setting below no cache headers rules on refresh(Or in your constructor):

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```